# Dynamically remove a product from queryset if added to cart -- django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

This is my original thought on how to accomplish this:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
for product in products:
  if product in cart:
    products = Product.objects.exclude(product)
```

My two questions are:
1.) Does this work/ make sense?
2.) Which .py file would I put it in?

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Dropoff, DropoffItem
from products.models import Product

from .forms import AddDropoffItemForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def add_item_dropoff_order(request):
    request.session.set_expiry(120000)

    try:
        user = request.user
        the_id = request.session['dropoff_id']              
        dropoff = Dropoff.objects.get(id=the_id)            
    except:
        user = request.user                                 
        new_dropoff_order = Dropoff(user=user)              
        new_dropoff_order.save()
        request.session['dropoff_id'] = new_dropoff_order.id            

        the_id = new_dropoff_order.id
        dropoff = Dropoff.objects.get(id=the_id)                    

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(sku=sku) 
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass

    form = AddDropoffItemForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":

        product_sku = str(request.POST['product'])

        dropoff_item = DropoffItem.objects.create(dropoff=dropoff, product_id=product_sku)  

        dropoff_item.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect('%s'%(reverse('add_item_dropoff_order')))

    context = {

        "dropoff": dropoff,
        "form": form,

    }
    return render(request, 'dropoffs/add_item_dropoff_order.html', context)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Dropoff, DropoffItem

from products.models import Product

class AddDropoffItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = DropoffItem
        fields = ["product"]
```

So basically, once dropoff_item.save() occurs, I want to remove that product from the queryset being called in the forms.py file.

Is it possible to redefine the queryset in the views and then call it again in the forms.py?

Comment: You still need a way to filter the products queryset in the form, which means you're going to need to pass some value to use to `.exclude()` by

Comment: Also, it's a bad idea to swallow exception errors the way you're doing. It gives you zero insight as to why the code failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, not really :)  I would approach this like:

   `products = Product.objects.exclude(id__in=cart.product_ids)`
2. Without seeing your application logic, it's impossible to tell you where to put this code, but since you've tagged django views, I'm assuming you want it in a view.

Comment: Rolled back the edit to my answer by @jingo because it's not clear exactly what type of object(s) or primitives the cart contains.

Comment: I agree, better this way.